# Make mouse pointer invisible on idle

Tags: windows, cursor

Is there a way to make the mouse pointer disappear when the computer goes idle?  If the solution could work in both Windows XP and Windows 7, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what I found [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic26076.html), I was able to make the following [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) code:

```
SystemCursor("Init")

SetTimer, CheckIdle, 250
return

CheckIdle:
TimeIdle := A_TimeIdlePhysical // 1000
if TimeIdle >= 3
{
    SystemCursor("Off")
}
else
{
    SystemCursor("On")
}
return

#Persistent
OnExit, ShowCursor  ; Ensure the cursor is made visible when the script exits.
return

ShowCursor:
SystemCursor("On")
ExitApp

SystemCursor(OnOff=1)   ; INIT = "I","Init"; OFF = 0,"Off"; TOGGLE = -1,"T","Toggle"; ON = others
{
    static AndMask, XorMask, $, h_cursor
        ,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13 ; system cursors
        , b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13   ; blank cursors
        , h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9,h10,h11,h12,h13   ; handles of default cursors
    if (OnOff = "Init" or OnOff = "I" or $ = "")       ; init when requested or at first call
    {
        $ = h                                          ; active default cursors
        VarSetCapacity( h_cursor,4444, 1 )
        VarSetCapacity( AndMask, 32*4, 0xFF )
        VarSetCapacity( XorMask, 32*4, 0 )
        system_cursors = 32512,32513,32514,32515,32516,32642,32643,32644,32645,32646,32648,32649,32650
        StringSplit c, system_cursors, `,
        Loop %c0%
        {
            h_cursor   := DllCall( "LoadCursor", "uint",0, "uint",c%A_Index% )
            h%A_Index% := DllCall( "CopyImage",  "uint",h_cursor, "uint",2, "int",0, "int",0, "uint",0 )
            b%A_Index% := DllCall("CreateCursor","uint",0, "int",0, "int",0
                , "int",32, "int",32, "uint",&AndMask, "uint",&XorMask )
        }
    }
    if (OnOff = 0 or OnOff = "Off" or $ = "h" and (OnOff < 0 or OnOff = "Toggle" or OnOff = "T"))
        $ = b  ; use blank cursors
    else
        $ = h  ; use the saved cursors

    Loop %c0%
    {
        h_cursor := DllCall( "CopyImage", "uint",%$%%A_Index%, "uint",2, "int",0, "int",0, "uint",0 )
        DllCall( "SetSystemCursor", "uint",h_cursor, "uint",c%A_Index% )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Cursor Hider](http://cursor-hider.en.softonic.com/)

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but $20 seems like a bit much.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind that little coding will be probably necessary, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). See [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic46209.html) forum post for more info on what you want to achieve.

Comment: The post you linked to only makes the mouse invisible in the AutoHotkey application created.  You got me on the right track though, so I'll give you an upvote.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

8 years on and [Joseph's](https://superuser.com/a/68302/442992) answer is still good and works in AHK!
BUT I have made it even better.. in my opinion of cause.

I have added a mouse check so the cursor only shows again when it is moved. True that I could have added other mouse events like  clicks but since the cursor is hidden I think it too edge case to bother. You are free to add it yourself if you want it :)

What I changed was move `#Persistent` to the top as it is global and present for the entire script no matter it is.

Added `CoordMode, Mouse, Screen` and `MouseGetPos, ix, iy` in autoexec section and `MouseGetPos, ix, iy` again when going to idle. `MouseGetPos, cx, cy` gets set on every `CheckIdle` and the variables are compared on mouse movement with `if (cx != ix or cy != iy)`.

```
#Persistent

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, ix, iy

SystemCursor("Init")

SetTimer, CheckIdle, 250
return

CheckIdle:
MouseGetPos, cx, cy
TimeIdle := A_TimeIdlePhysical // 1000
if (TimeIdle >= 3)
{
    MouseGetPos, ix, iy
    SystemCursor("Off")
}
else if (cx != ix or cy != iy)
{
    SystemCursor("On")
}
return

OnExit, ShowCursor  ; Ensure the cursor is made visible when the script exits.
return

ShowCursor:
SystemCursor("On")
ExitApp

SystemCursor(OnOff=1)   ; INIT = "I","Init"; OFF = 0,"Off"; TOGGLE = -1,"T","Toggle"; ON = others
{
    static AndMask, XorMask, $, h_cursor
        ,c0,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13 ; system cursors
        , b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13   ; blank cursors
        , h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9,h10,h11,h12,h13   ; handles of default cursors
    if (OnOff = "Init" or OnOff = "I" or $ = "")       ; init when requested or at first call
    {
        $ = h                                          ; active default cursors
        VarSetCapacity( h_cursor,4444, 1 )
        VarSetCapacity( AndMask, 32*4, 0xFF )
        VarSetCapacity( XorMask, 32*4, 0 )
        system_cursors = 32512,32513,32514,32515,32516,32642,32643,32644,32645,32646,32648,32649,32650
        StringSplit c, system_cursors, `,
        Loop %c0%
        {
            h_cursor   := DllCall( "LoadCursor", "uint",0, "uint",c%A_Index% )
            h%A_Index% := DllCall( "CopyImage",  "uint",h_cursor, "uint",2, "int",0, "int",0, "uint",0 )
            b%A_Index% := DllCall("CreateCursor","uint",0, "int",0, "int",0
                , "int",32, "int",32, "uint",&AndMask, "uint",&XorMask )
        }
    }
    if (OnOff = 0 or OnOff = "Off" or $ = "h" and (OnOff < 0 or OnOff = "Toggle" or OnOff = "T"))
        $ = b  ; use blank cursors
    else
        $ = h  ; use the saved cursors

    Loop %c0%
    {
        h_cursor := DllCall( "CopyImage", "uint",%$%%A_Index%, "uint",2, "int",0, "int",0, "uint",0 )
        DllCall( "SetSystemCursor", "uint",h_cursor, "uint",c%A_Index% )
    }
}
```